# Index not being used on array elements in JSONB column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `testuser` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE testuser (id int, data jsonb);
```

where the following snippet shows the format of the `data` column:

```
INSERT INTO testuser (id, data) VALUES (1, '{
  "name": "peter",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "type": "ARTICLE",
      "aggregateReference": "ae8b9fed-f99b-498e-b9ab-b87b1eec94a7"
    }
  ]
}'::jsonb);
```

Now, I've created a `gin` index on the `permissions` field like this:

```
CREATE INDEX test_user_permission_ix ON testuser USING gin((data -> 'permissions'));
```

but when I try to generate some additional rows, and run a query, the index is not being used:

```
SET enable_seqscan=false;
INSERT INTO testuser SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,100);
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM testuser WHERE data @> '{"permissions" : [{"type":"ARTICLE"}]}';
                                                        QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on testuser  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000170.01 rows=10 width=141) (actual time=26.040..26.453 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: (data @> '{"permissions": [{"type": "ARTICLE"}]}'::jsonb)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 10000
 Planning Time: 0.051 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 2
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 0.327 ms, Inlining 3.541 ms, Optimization 16.740 ms, Emission 5.626 ms, Total 26.233 ms
 Execution Time: 26.861 ms
(9 rows)
```

I can see in the `pg_indexes` table that the type of the `permissions` field seem to be `::text`, but I'm not sure if this affects anything:

```
 schemaname | tablename |        indexname        | tablespace |                                              indexdef
------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 public     | testuser  | test_user_permission_ix |            | CREATE INDEX test_user_permission_ix ON public.testuser USING gin (((data -> 'permissions'::text)))
```

Any suggestions on why the index is not being used would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left hand side of the WHERE expression must match the expression in the index, in order for the index to be usable (because the index stores a copy of that expression's value).

As your index is created on the expression `data -> 'permissions'` you need to use that in the query:

```
select *
from testuser
where data -> 'permissions' @> '[{"type":"ARTICLE"}]';
```

Note that this doesn't guarantee that the index is used. If the condition returns a substantial part of the table, the Seq Scan is still faster.

---

For the condition `data @> '{"permissions": [{"type": "ARTICLE"}]}'` you would need to create an index on `data` (not an expression)